# TypeScript: Record-style type based on generic type describing arbitrary fields and their required types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to express my types so that when I call my code like so:

```
type Topics = {
  documentList: Document[];
};

const TopicsContainer = useTopicsContainer<Topics>(['documentList']);
```

the array passed in as argument to `useTopicsContainer` is constrained to the fields defined in `Topics`. An example implementation of `useTopicsContainer` could be as follows:

```
const useTopicsContainer = <TopicsTypes>(
  topics: (keyof TopicsTypes)[]
): TopicsState<TopicsTypes> => {
  const initialState: TopicsState<TopicsTypes> = {};
  const [topicsState, setTopicsState] = useState<TopicsState<TopicsTypes>>(
    initialState
  );

  // some code mutating the state by calling setTopicsState, like e.g.
  setInterval(
    () =>
      setTopicsState(
        Object.fromEntries(
          topics.map((topic) => [topic, createRandomDocument()])
        )
      ),
    1000
  );

  return topicsState;
};
```

I'd like to derive the `TopicsState` type from the generic `TopicsTypes`. So far I've tried:

```
type TopicsState<TopicTypes> = Record<
  keyof TopicTypes,
  TopicTypes[keyof TopicTypes]
>;
```

but that yields a `TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'TopicsState '.` for `const initialState: TopicsState<TopicsTypes> = {};`

Another attempt:

```
interface TopicsState<TopicTypes> {
  [topic: keyof TopicTypes]: TopicTypes[keyof TopicTypes];
}
```

…but that results in `TS1023: An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'.` for the `topic` key. I'm running out of ideas… if you'd like to give this one a go, below is a sandbox with all of the above code cobbled together. Thanks!

[image: Edit nice-carson-uk58n]

## Edit

As suggested by [Alex Wayne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62076/alex-wayne), adding `Partial` to `TopicsState` allows an empty object literal to be a `TopicsState`. I've updated the CodeSandbox example with that. The only remaining issue is that now I cannot assign a value to a field in `topicsState`, getting `Type '{ [k: string]: Document; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<Record<keyof TopicsTypes, TopicsTypes[keyof TopicsTypes]>>'.ts(2345)`. On the bright side, the type checks on the consumer side in `App.tsx` work exactly as expected:

```
const TopicsContainer = useTopicsContainer<Topics>(["documentList"]);
const documentList: Document[] = TopicsContainer.documentList || [];
```

If I change `documentList: Document[]` to `documentList: string`, I get the desired `Type 'Document[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)`.
Is there a way to relax the constraint in the implementation of `useTopicsContainer`?

Comment: When I open that CodeSandbox link I get a lot of seemingly unrelated errors like "Expression expected" on `const`.  Could you provide a [mcve] where the only issues present are the ones you're asking about?  Ideally it would be something that could be dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (code link)](https://tsplay.dev/NBzq4N).

Comment: I think that error means that an empty object `{}` cannot be assigned to an interface with required properties. `const initialState: Partial<TopicsTypes> = {};` should work. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503846/create-objects-dynamically-in-typescript Also, I'm fairly sure that your first `TopicsState` does nothing because a type that sets all keys of an object to all values of those keys is just... that... object.

Comment: @jcalz thanks, I've updated the CodeSandbox example—my bad, apologies!

Comment: I'm still a bit confused here; it looks like `topicsState`, as implemented, is going to have properties of type `Document`, not `Document[]`.  Is there something with arrays that I'm not getting?  My inclination here would be to write a solution like [this code](https://tsplay.dev/WYJbbw), but without understanding what's going on with `Document[]` vs `Document`, I can't be sure.  Help?

Comment: Hey @jcalz, it's irrelevant if it's `Document` or `Document[]`—my goal was defining an arbitrary mapping of keys on the topics state to types, so that parts of the application which use `topicsState` are informed of what type is stored under which key. I intentionally simplified the example to leave out details like using Websockets. The mistake in them that I made, is using `Document[]` in the implementation, which is too specific, and it should not be a big surprise this doesn't type check. I now have a working solution which I'll post as an answer in a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type I was after goes as follows:

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
type TopicsState<TopicTypes> = Partial<
  Record<keyof TopicTypes, ValueOf<TopicTypes>>
>;
```

with it, I can now use it like so:

```
type Topics = {
  documentList: Document[];
};
const TopicsContainer = useTopicsContainer<Topics>(["documentList"]);
const documentList: Document[] = TopicsContainer.documentList || [];
```

This way, `TopicsContainer` knows that under the key of `"documentList"` the type is `Document[]`.

For a full example checkout the sandbox:
[image: Edit nice-carson-uk58n]

For posterity:

```
// useTopicsContainer.ts
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";

type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
type TopicsState<TopicTypes> = Partial<
  Record<keyof TopicTypes, ValueOf<TopicTypes>>
>;
type KeysOfTopicsState<TopicTypes> = Extract<keyof TopicTypes, string>[];

const client = io("/topics");

const useTopicsContainer = <TopicsTypes>(
  topics: KeysOfTopicsState<TopicsTypes>
): TopicsState<TopicsTypes> => {
  const initialState: TopicsState<TopicsTypes> = {};
  const [topicsState, setTopicsState] = useState<TopicsState<TopicsTypes>>(
    initialState
  );

  // some code mutating the state by calling setTopicsState, like e.g.
  useEffect(() => {
    const topicListeners = Object.fromEntries(
      topics.map((topic) => [
        topic,
        (topicData: ValueOf<TopicsTypes>) => {
          setTopicsState((oldState) => ({
            ...oldState,
            [topic]: topicData
          }));
        }
      ])
    );

    topics.forEach((topic) => {
      client.on(topic as string, topicListeners[topic]);
    });

    return () => {
      topics.forEach((topic) => {
        client.off(topic, topicListeners[topic]);
      });
    };
  });

  return topicsState;
};

export default useTopicsContainer;
```

```
// App.tsx
import React from "react";
import useTopicsContainer from "./useTopicsContainer";

type Topics = {
  documentList: Document[];
};

export default function App() {
  const TopicsContainer = useTopicsContainer<Topics>(["documentList"]);
  const documentList: Document[] = TopicsContainer.documentList || [];

  console.log({ documentList });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thanks to [Alex Wayne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62076/alex-wayne) and [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) for the suggestions, rubber ducking and keeping my examples straight!